# android: create variables names programatically for a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with 10 items each having an audio file.

I want to create mediaplayer variables with their names like media1, media2 .... media[total number of items in the recyclerview]

then in onBindview i want to use variable names corresponding to the position .

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    mp = media+"position"
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(), Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/" + planDetailLists.get(i - 2).placechildplaces_audiodetailfilename));
    mp.start();
    }
```

Why i am doing this is, I want each item to remember its mediaplayer variable, so that i can play pause that particular audio file only and not the other items audio file.

Else what i found is, audio of other item is played when i press play button of another item. If i pause an items[1[ audio, and play the other items[2] audio, it continues item[1] audio from the its pause position.

I am not able to manager the audio files of each item. everything is getting mixed up.

Comment: Do as String.valueOf(position);

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: or is there a way to track the mediaplayer instance for that particular item

Comment: you need only one `MediaPlayer` instance, why do you create a new `MediaPlayer` for each item?

Comment: example mp = Mediaplayer.create ... creates  variable with Mediaplayer@83439893847 . So how to save that instance. so that i can call it again

Comment: assign it to some class field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113920/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to take it as dynamic variable, when you can easily do this by array of mediaplayer.

Just declare one array variable for mediaplayer and then when you get data at that time initialize it and then in viewholder use it.

```
 MediaPlayer allMPlayers[];
```

after getting data initialize it as,

```
 allMPlayers = new MediaPlayer[list.size()];
```

now use in holder as below,

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

      mp = allMPlayers[position];
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(), Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/" + planDetailLists.get(i - 2).placechildplaces_audiodetailfilename));
      mp.start();
 }
```

Comment: I have  play/pause button on my item. Each item will have different audio file.  i want the audio to be still playing if i go back. So how to refer to the mediaplayer variable which is already running when i come back to this audio list page

Answer (score 0):

For this, the easiest thing is to use a `HashMap<String, MediaPlayer>`. So you would put/get the media player from the map by its string name.

**EDIT:**

Or remember the the `MediaPlayer` instance in your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` implementation. But beware of holders recycling.

**EDIT 2:**

To remember a `MediaPlayer` instance in a view holder you would save it in the `onBindViewHolder` method. Example:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    // First cast to your view holder implementation which has a public instance variable MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    // Just for easy access of instance variables
    MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder)viewHolder;

    if (holder.mediaPlayer == null) {
        // If there is no MediaPlayer on this view holder create a new one.
        holder.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(), Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/" + planDetailLists.get(i - 2).placechildplaces_audiodetailfilename));
        mp.start();
    }
    else {
        // Stop playing this media player...

        // Re-use the current media player or create a new one...

        // Now play the new sound with similar code as in the IF branch above...
    }
}
```

Comment: How to remember the instance of the MediaPlayer

Comment: i tried edit2. I have play/pause button on each of my items. I have different audifiles for different items to play. This approach created a new Mediaplayer for the first item on clicking play, but for the second item, when i click play. it continues playing the first mediaplayer, the same audio file, instead of creating a new one.